# problem with Neo4j query, calling foreach for the previous match results

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher

I have this class (node):

```
case class User(name: String, lastName: String, age: Int, city: String)
```

I'm trying to add relationships for an existing node (name=Alice) with this query:

```
MATCH (user:User {name: $name}),(friend:User) WHERE friend.name IN [$fNames] WITH user,friend CREATE (user)-[f:FRIEND]->(friend) RETURN f
```

I'm passing in fNames = List(Bob, David), and all nodes exist in db (for Alice, Bob and David).
This query returns no results, and that one neither:

```
MATCH (user:User {name: $name})-[f:FRIEND]->(friend:User) RETURN friend
```

I tried using FOREACH in the first query but was getting errors (something about Nodes vs Paths).
My goal is to add FRIEND relationships (edges) between Alice and all User nodes (vertices) with "name" field in fNames list.
How can I do that using a single cipher query?
Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Since `$fNames` is already a list, `[$fNames]` would enclose that list within another list -- which is not what you intended. You should just use `$fNames` as-is:

```
MATCH (user:User {name: $name}), (friend:User)
WHERE friend.name IN $fNames
CREATE (user)-[f:FRIEND]->(friend)
RETURN f
```

Also, to speed up this query, you should consider creating an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:User(name)`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I up-voted your answer but I have < 15 rep so it's not going to show. Thanks!